Alternatives to if_all and if_any for Data Manipulation in R
I have been using the if_all and if_any functions from the dplyr package for data manipulation in R. However, I have noticed that these functions can be quite slow when handling large datasets. Therefore, I am looking for alternatives available in the collapse or kit R packages.
While I attempted to use the collapse package, I am not obtaining the expected results. Below is the output from my R code, which illustrates the discrepancies I encountered:
library(tidyverse)
library(collapse)

set.seed(12345)
df1 <-
  data.frame(
    A1 = runif(n = 10, min = 1, max = 3) %>% round
  , A2 = runif(n = 10, min = 1, max = 4) %>% round
  , A3 = runif(n = 10, min = 1, max = 5) %>% round
  )

df1
#>    A1 A2 A3
#> 1   2  1  3
#> 2   3  1  2
#> 3   3  3  5
#> 4   3  1  4
#> 5   2  2  4
#> 6   1  2  3
#> 7   2  2  4
#> 8   2  2  3
#> 9   2  2  2
#> 10  3  4  3

df1 %>% 
  mutate(
    A4 = if_all(c(A2, A3), \(x) x %in% c(1, 2))
  , A5 = if_any(c(A2, A3), \(x) x %in% c(1, 2))
    )
#>    A1 A2 A3    A4    A5
#> 1   2  1  3 FALSE  TRUE
#> 2   3  1  2  TRUE  TRUE
#> 3   3  3  5 FALSE FALSE
#> 4   3  1  4 FALSE  TRUE
#> 5   2  2  4 FALSE  TRUE
#> 6   1  2  3 FALSE  TRUE
#> 7   2  2  4 FALSE  TRUE
#> 8   2  2  3 FALSE  TRUE
#> 9   2  2  2  TRUE  TRUE
#> 10  3  4  3 FALSE FALSE
  
df1 %>% 
  fmutate(
    A4 = fsum(fselect(., A2, A3) %in% c(1, 2)) == 2
  , A5 = fsum(fselect(., A2, A3) %in% c(1, 2)) >= 1
    )
#>    A1 A2 A3    A4    A5
#> 1   2  1  3 FALSE FALSE
#> 2   3  1  2 FALSE FALSE
#> 3   3  3  5 FALSE FALSE
#> 4   3  1  4 FALSE FALSE
#> 5   2  2  4 FALSE FALSE
#> 6   1  2  3 FALSE FALSE
#> 7   2  2  4 FALSE FALSE
#> 8   2  2  3 FALSE FALSE
#> 9   2  2  2 FALSE FALSE
#> 10  3  4  3 FALSE FALSE

How can I properly implement alternatives to if_all and if_any using the collapse or kit packages?

What’s wrong with all or any? They are vectorized and return length one logical.

if_all and if_any are very slow for actual data. So exploring some fast alternatives.

@IRTFM: if_all and if_any are by row, whereas all and any are by column.

Aside from the bug in your fmutate code (I think fselect(...) %in% isn't doing what you think it is), I'm curious about if if_all and if_any are really the issue and not the %in%. Have you zeroed on exactly where the performance issues are?

Depends on how big your data is. If not too big, use if_all/if_any. If moderately big, consider data.table, although R is C-major and thus still will be abit row, Otherwise Write a basic C/fortran/Rcpp code to fulfill your goal

You don't say if you're also using the collapse version of %in%, but if not, I'd start there.
See the help page for fmatch, where it suggests setting the %in% to use a faster version based on fmatch by running
set_collapse(mask = "%in%")

I'd then try running your initial code again. When I do this with an initial data size of 1e7 rows, the runtime drops from 1.6s to 0.6s.
I thought boolean operators might be faster too, but when I compared this code it was actually slower than the initial code.
df1 %>% 
  mutate(
    A4 = (A2==1 | A2==2) & (A3==1 | A3==2),
    A5 = (A2==1 | A2==2) | (A3==1 | A3==2)
  )


Actually base R approaches are good enough to achieve decent speed, see f2() and f3(), where matrix and %in% are needed only as the core parts. However, their performance gain depends on the size of data you want to manipulate.

Benchmark Template
Below is a benchmarking example with N <- 1e6 rows of df1
set.seed(0)
N <- 1e6
df1 <-
    data.frame(
        A1 = runif(n = N, min = 1, max = 3) %>% round(),
        A2 = runif(n = N, min = 1, max = 4) %>% round(),
        A3 = runif(n = N, min = 1, max = 5) %>% round()
    )

f0 <- function() {
    df1 %>%
        mutate(
            A4 = if_all(c(A2, A3), \(x) x %in% c(1, 2)),
            A5 = if_any(c(A2, A3), \(x) x %in% c(1, 2))
        )
}

f1 <- function() {
    df1 %>%
        mutate(
            A4 = (A2 == 1 | A2 == 2) & (A3 == 1 | A3 == 2),
            A5 = (A2 == 1 | A2 == 2) | (A3 == 1 | A3 == 2)
        )
}

f2 <- function() {
    v <- with(df1, matrix(c(A2, A3) %in% c(1, 2), nrow(df1)))
    v1 <- v[, 1]
    v2 <- v[, 2]
    transform(df1, A4 = v1 & v2, A5 = v1 | v2)
}

f3 <- function() {
    p <- with(df1, rowSums(matrix(c(A2, A3) %in% c(1, 2), nrow(df1))))
    transform(df1, A4 = p == 2, A5 = p > 0)
}

f4 <- function() {
    collapse::set_collapse(mask = "%in%")
    df1 %>%
        mutate(
            A4 = if_all(c(A2, A3), \(x) x %in% c(1, 2)),
            A5 = if_any(c(A2, A3), \(x) x %in% c(1, 2))
        )
}

microbenchmark(
    f0 = f0(),
    f1 = f1(),
    f2 = f2(),
    f3 = f3(),
    f4 = f4(),
    times = 50L,
    check = "equal",
    unit = "relative"
)

and you will see that
Unit: relative
 expr      min        lq      mean   median        uq       max neval
   f0 1.047778 1.0104420 0.9218966 1.043092 0.8715391 0.8610043    50
   f1 1.395724 1.3236532 1.2018580 1.372736 1.1703099 0.9842568    50
   f2 1.000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.000000 1.0000000 1.0000000    50
   f3 1.000392 0.9877969 0.9856109 1.010155 0.9277639 0.9878603    50
   f4 1.040411 0.9982666 0.8961318 1.058850 0.9010900 0.7101930    50


Scenarios with more different size options

When N <- 1e1

Unit: relative
 expr        min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
   f0 23.4931129 14.399805 11.503096 17.324799 20.330680 1.4486113    50
   f1  7.8181818  4.911965  4.193111  6.096767  6.803546 1.2193533    50
   f2  0.9807163  1.105058  1.705410  1.107833  1.399059 0.9914068    50
   f3  1.0000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000 1.0000000    50
   f4 24.6749311 15.020428 11.158707 16.653938 19.934515 1.2438078    50


When N <- 1e2

Unit: relative
 expr        min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
   f0 19.8663507 17.347484 15.321237 13.628332 12.614826 16.730800    50
   f1  6.8104265  6.041667  4.020308  4.890386  4.445308  1.710434    50
   f2  0.9829384  1.033019  1.102217  1.010183  1.005184  1.234446    50
   f3  1.0000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000    50
   f4 20.3023697 17.755503 11.103007 14.106619 12.934163  2.112398    50


When N <- 1e3

Unit: relative
 expr        min         lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
   f0 17.8580122 14.0827101 10.403730 13.651585 14.62880 1.830803    50
   f1  6.1162948  4.6075671  4.101737  4.487400  4.56672 1.772511    50
   f2  0.9391481  0.9577651  1.107033  1.051165  1.04864 1.521045    50
   f3  1.0000000  1.0000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.00000 1.000000    50
   f4 17.7133198 13.5213374 10.643525 13.396144 14.04736 2.732394    50


When N <- 1e4

Unit: relative
 expr      min        lq      mean   median       uq       max neval
   f0 6.167672 6.6591692 6.0338451 6.507537 6.620002 1.9110550    50
   f1 3.095537 2.7808816 2.5381326 2.644488 2.673983 1.2172201    50
   f2 1.010615 0.9718846 0.9661573 1.020097 1.037727 0.7314582    50
   f3 1.000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.0000000    50
   f4 6.234017 6.1897334 5.0731751 5.824909 5.832958 1.2777907    50


When N <- 1e5

Unit: relative
 expr       min        lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
   f0 1.8238810 1.8866540 1.642417 1.983972 1.976608 1.283589    50
   f1 1.6533745 1.7394664 1.561517 1.747545 1.822362 1.367563    50
   f2 0.8473692 0.9923251 1.046288 1.042178 1.115207 1.088582    50
   f3 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    50
   f4 1.6510173 1.8395745 1.580477 1.818549 1.895823 1.142620    50


When N <- 1e7

Unit: relative
 expr      min        lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
   f0 1.092387 0.9832837 1.030079 1.035062 1.045268 1.084763    50
   f1 1.602960 1.4320552 1.440598 1.448340 1.418036 1.479628    50
   f2 1.143190 1.0427111 1.046079 1.063290 1.046721 1.022088    50
   f3 1.191823 1.0551980 1.058584 1.078189 1.063206 1.043298    50
   f4 1.000000 1.0000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    50


Using collapse %in% for f3() as f3_3() at N <- 1e7, outperforms f4(), median 1.000000, 1.213481 (f3_3, f4 respectively).

@Chris yes, that could boost the base R approaches.

Adding the base and I guess idiomatic R alternative based on Reduce:
df1$A4<-Reduce("&", lapply(df1[,c("A2","A3")], \(x) x %in% 1:2))
df1$A5<-Reduce("|", lapply(df1[,c("A2","A3")], \(x) x %in% 1:2))

